i have trouble in building abseil using vcpkg
Iam trying to build aseil for MSVC17. the build is not generated corectly.
I have tried by reinstalling the VCPKG package manager and also check for log files. I thought proving the error logs would help someone to guied me.
for more details i have rised an issue in git
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/39509
in this git issue, i have given the "D:\vcpkg\installed\vcpkg\issue_body.md" file that shows the errors.
iam trying to build aseil to build opencv. aseil is a dependency of opencv
here is the file content for D:\vcpkg\buildtrees\abseil\config-x64-windows-dbg-err.log
CMake Error at CMake/AbseilHelpers.cmake:317 (target_link_libraries):
The link interface of target "test_allocator" contains:
GTest::gmock

but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:
* There is a typo in the target name.
* A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
* An ALIAS target is missing.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
absl/container/CMakeLists.txt:206 (absl_cc_library)
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
FETCHCONTENT_FULLY_DISCONNECTED
_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Here is the port file:
if (NOT VCPKG_TARGET_IS_WINDOWS)
    vcpkg_check_linkage(ONLY_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endif()

vcpkg_from_github(
    OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
    REPO abseil/abseil-cpp
    REF "${VERSION}"
    SHA512 5062e731ee8c9a757e6d75fc1c558652deb4dd1daab4d6143f7ad52a139501c61365f89acbf82480be0f9a4911a58286560068d8b1a8b6774e6afad51739766e
    HEAD_REF master
    PATCHES
        0001-revert-integer-to-string-conversion-optimizations.patch # Fix openvino MSVC compile error
)

vcpkg_check_features(OUT_FEATURE_OPTIONS FEATURE_OPTIONS
    FEATURES
        cxx17 ABSL_USE_CXX17
)

# With ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON abseil automatically detect if it is being
# compiled with C++14 or C++17, and modifies the installed `absl/base/options.h`
# header accordingly. This works even if CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD is not set. Abseil
# uses the compiler default behavior to update `absl/base/options.h` as needed.
if (ABSL_USE_CXX17)
    set(ABSL_USE_CXX17_OPTION "-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17")
endif ()

vcpkg_cmake_configure(
    SOURCE_PATH "${SOURCE_PATH}"
    DISABLE_PARALLEL_CONFIGURE
    OPTIONS
        -DABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON
        ${ABSL_USE_CXX17_OPTION}
)

vcpkg_cmake_install()
vcpkg_cmake_config_fixup(PACKAGE_NAME absl CONFIG_PATH lib/cmake/absl)
vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig()

vcpkg_copy_pdbs()
file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/share"
                    "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/debug/include"
                    "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/include/absl/copts"
                    "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/include/absl/strings/testdata"
                    "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/include/absl/time/internal/cctz/testdata"
)

if (VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE STREQUAL "dynamic")
    file(GLOB_RECURSE headers "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/include/absl/*.h")
    foreach(header IN LISTS ${headers})
        vcpkg_replace_string("${header}"
            "!defined(ABSL_CONSUME_DLL)" "0"
        )
        vcpkg_replace_string("${header}"
            "defined(ABSL_CONSUME_DLL)" "1"
        )
    endforeach()
endif()

vcpkg_install_copyright(FILE_LIST "${SOURCE_PATH}/LICENSE")


I see you have the issue raised. It depends on the developers on how fast it gets fixed.  In my experience with vcpkg some projects take a long time (months) for problems like this while others are fixed quickly.

For a StackOverflow question you probably want to edit your question and add the port file and D:\vcpkg\buildtrees\abseil\config-x64-windows-dbg-err.log the first few lines show some problem with the targets from GoogleTest.

On Stack Overflow we expect the question post to contain all information relevant to the problem. A link to an off-site resource, where the problem is described, is not sufficient.

@drescherjm @Tsyvarev i have update the question with D:\vcpkg\buildtrees\abseil\config-x64-windows-dbg-err.log. will this help to diagnose the problem? thanks

I copied the port file to the question. The odd thing here is I see no mention of GoogleTest so it appears to me to be an upstream problem.

I expect you could disable testing by adding -DABSL_BUILD_TESTING=OFF after -DABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD=ON

I don't use gmock however I found this: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-mark-gmock-as-a-required-component/10106
